# Change html background on refresh with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I want to change my background image of my html on every refresh.

This is what i got in my CSS

```
html { 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and this is what i got with javascript (in a separate js file) :

```
var totalCount = 6;
function ChangeBackground()
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
document.body.parentNode.background = 'background/test/'+num+'.jpg';

}
```

i call my function at the end of my html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeBackground();
</script>
```

I cannot add a background on html tag with the javascript-code i have. Is there any other way?

i want it specifically on the html tag, because i think thats better:

> We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the html element (better than body as it's always at least the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: But its not working... Doesn't help. What is not working?

Comment: I cannot add a background on html tag with the javascript-code i have. Is there any other way?

Comment: `var html = document.documentElement;` http://jsfiddle.net/8wGYF/1/

Comment: Updated example, showing the background switching - http://jsfiddle.net/8wGYF/2/ (hit "Run" for a refresh);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `background-image` style property value to a url instead of directly specifying the link

ie: Use `document.body.parentNode.style.backgroundImage = 'url(background/test/'+num+'.jpg)';` instead of `document.body.parentNode.background = 'background/test/'+num+'.jpg';`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHeKK/

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot add background to a `<html>` tag!

Change your code this way:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'background/test/'+num+'.jpg';
```

Comment: is there no way that i can add a background to a html tag with javascript? Because here it says that its better on a html tag then a body tag:  http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/